# Xpages Extension library name picker "peopleByLastName" list processing

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I found that the usage of the extension library name picker is somehow difficult when it comes to one certain case: I'd like to display people alphabetically by lastname in the selection and need their fullnames in return.

So, for returning the fullnames, the *dominoNABNamePicker* is the logical choice, and it seems that

```
<xe:dominoNABNamePicker nameList="peopleByLastName">/xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
```

does exactly what I need - but the resulting list is sorted by lastname **only**; inside of a certain lastname "block", people are shown sorted by creation date, oldest entries on top.

The base view used for displaying the entries is the *($VIMPeopleByLastName)* view in the names.nsf.

This leads me to my questions:
- can I sort the 'resulting' list somehow additionally by firstname and middleinitial before displaying it to the user, showing the nicely sorted result to select from?

- is there another data provider / parameter set which returns me the fullnames displaying a "Lastname, Firstname" selection of people? (e.g. 
*dominoViewNamePicker* data provider only returns the labelColumn, which is the same shown to select from)

- can I simply add 'ascending order' sort option to the firstname and middleinital columns of the *($VIMPeopleByLastName)* view, or will this have any negative effects somewhere else?
(I know this will be a pain in future releases, but seems to be the easiest way so far... )

Any further ideas also appreciated...

Comment: Please confirm which version of Extension Library you're using. I contributed a number of enhancements to the Name Picker dataProvider at the end of 2014 / beginning of 2015.

Comment: Hi Paul, we upgraded our server to Domino 9.0.1 FP 4 a few weeks ago, which I think comes directly including the extlib. Version is com.ibm.xsp.extlib_9.0.1.v00_00_20150605-1000 (so, timestamp says June 2015?)